# Change all wordpress permalink url in database

Tags: jekyll, wordpress

First of all i know that wordpress will redirect from old permalink to new.

But if I'm not using WordPress the old permalink will be dead.

### In example

```
http://www.example.com/%postname
```

I have changed to

```
http://www.example.com/%year/%date/%postname
```

In wordpress all traffic from old will be redirect to new but in database was not changed it's still old. Jekyll can't do this.

I want to fix this thing can anyone guide my way?

(I do this because I'm migrating to jekyll everything is OK but this one)

Comment: I understand that you're migrating from wp to jekyll. Did you tried that : https://github.com/benbalter/wordpress-to-jekyll-exporter ?

Comment: Yes i use that. But permalink is not changed

Comment: Does [jekyll-redirect-from](https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/) satisfy your requirements (for redirecting)? I can take a look at the WordPress database if you need automatic generation of redirect links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [plugin](https://github.com/nquinlan/jekyll-pageless-redirects) for redirects in Jekyll.

You can simply create a `_redirects.yml`, `_redirects.htaccess`, and/or `_redirects.json` file and set initial page address with an old link and a destination page with a new link.